# Solving an equation with exponents doubts

Tags: exponential-function

I have a demand function x = p^(-ed) 
and a supply function y = p^(-es)

Obviously this is an economics question, but to give some idea - I need to equate demand and supply, and find the equilibrium price - which is p in the equations. (And just a note, ed and es refer to the elasticities of demand and supply)

I don't understand how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried bringing the exponents down but couldn't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Hint: Logarithms.

Comment: $x = p^{-ed} = \frac 1{p^{ed}}$ so $p^{ed} = \frac 1x$ so $p = \sqrt[ed]{\frac 1x}$.

Comment: "I need to equate demand and supply" Not sure whay you mean.  Are you saying $s=d$ (in which case $x = y$)?

Comment: @fleablood:  I think it is implied that $ed$ (which might actually be $e_d$) is the *elasticity of demand* and that $es$ (which might actually be $e_s$) is the *elasticity of supply*.

Comment: But I want to solve this problem by not using a calculator?

Comment: @fleablood yes x will be equal to y, in order for the equilibrium price to emerge.

Comment: If you are trying to solve for $p$ when $y$ and $e_s$ are known then $y = p^{-e_s}$ so $\ln y = \ln p^{-e_s} =-e_s \ln p$ so $\ln p =- \frac{\ln y}{e_s}$ and $p = e^{- \frac{\ln y}{e_s}}=y^{-\frac 1{e_s}}$.

Comment: "But I want to solve this problem by not using a calculator?" Who said anything about a calculator?

Comment: Is there a sign missing? lt looks like both your demand and supply curve slope downward, and the supply curve should slope up.